How to buy tokens on solana
I been working on a project since 2 weeks and I am so frustrated. i am not able to understand. Can someone help me with writing the code of swapping spl tokens from SOL. I cannot understand, how the swap instruction is constructed and how, and how the transactions are done. I got to know that unlike web3 we have to fetch the pool address and then make up the transaction and do all at our own. Can someone please help me with this.

You should dig into the SDK and documentations of protocols you want execute swap transaction, likely Raydium or Jupitor.
It would also depend on the specific requirements, like if you're trying to swap the existing spl token, or with the market and pool you created yourself.
the basic approach it to fetch pool keys from https://api.raydium.io/v2/sdk/liquidity/mainnet.json
and filter the data for your needs.
or it you have a specific token in mind, you and simply find the pool id in the analytic platform like Birdeye.
